# Asp.net core copy solution from another computer

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.Net core 2.0.0 MVC solution.
I copied the solution from another computer. 
Now the solution error, could not find reference for "Controller" and others, even I installed ASP.Net core MVC from Nuget.

I guessed that we should change reference for the solution.
Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how familiar you are with .NET Core, so I'll start from the beginning.

First, make sure you have the latest SDK from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

You can check and make sure your SDK is installed properly and you have the correct version by opening a command prompt and running the command `dotnet --version`

Next, in the command prompt you can navigate to the project directory and issue the command `dotnet build`  (This is new in .NET Core 2.0, the `dotnet restore` command is executed for you if packages need to be restored)

Unless there is a problem with the repository you downloaded, this should result in a successful build.

Also, if you haven't done so, I highly recommend reading up on the .NET Core CLI: Next you'll need to familliarize yourself with the .NET Core CLI :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: thanks for your supporting, but there are still error. I'll investigate then come back here